# Carla 0.9.14 system requirement

Tags: python-3.x, simulator, carla

I am running carla on my TUF A15 laptop.
Initial configurations and vehicle spawning runs super fast but when i try to run pygame modules and camera sensors my simulator always crash

here are my system specs
OS - Windows 11 64bit
RAM - 16GB
GPU - RTX 3050 GDDR6 @4GB (128 bits)
Processor - Ryzen 7 4800H Radeon Graphics